# How to create temporary accounts and IAM users for labs for each user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

The cloud labs on Pluralsight (the training site), they create a new account with one IAM User each time when start a lab.

I would like to implement similar logic on my own, how can I do that?

My current idea is to create a member account using the AWS Organization Unit, but I'm looking for another method due to difficulties in the account deletion process and limit of service quota.

The expectation is to be able to create a new temporary account whenever the user requests it.

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for is Cloudformation StackSets. It follows a 1 parent to multiple child accounts hierarchy, you can deploy CF stacks in these child accounts of your choosing - thus creating a new user and other resources.

Comment: My intention is to issue accounts to users and allow them to practice creating various resources. This is because, when issued on an account basis rather than by IAM User, resource isolation between users is clear and resource name duplication problems do not occur.

Is using Cloudformation StackSets the appropriate approach in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This type of Labs environment has been used by AWS Training, QwikLabs and other companies.

The general flow is:

- Have a whole lot of **AWS Accounts** and their `root` credentials
- When a student starts a lab, grab one of the accounts and track that it has been allocated to a user
- Provision an **IAM User** with sufficient permissions to perform the lab
- If appropriate, trigger the creation of a **CloudFormation stack** to provision initial infrastructure (eg VPC, database, EC2 instance)
- When the student has finished (or after a set time period):

  - Delete the **IAM User**
  - Delete all **resources** created in the account (eg using [GitHub - rebuy-de/aws-nuke: Nuke a whole AWS account and delete all its resources.](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke))
  - Update tracking so that the account can be used by somebody else

The above is **inherently dangerous if exposed publicly** because people might attempt to use the accounts for sinister purposes (storing/serving movies, generating bitcoin, spamming, etc). It is extremely important to **limit the ability to create IAM entities** otherwise temporary credentials can be generated that can be hard to delete. Any IAM permissions required should be supplied as part of the lab creation process and should be locked-down as much as possible. You have been warned!

AWS will charge you for all resources generated by the account. Don't go crying to them if you left a gap in your security and allowed somebody to spin-up expensive EC2 instances. It is *your* responsibility to maintain appropriate security on the accounts and monitor their usage. I **recommend activating AWS CloudTrail on each account** so you can see what has been done to the account, and remove permissions for students to be able to modify/delete those Trails.

If you are provisioning accounts only for use within your company, then you hopefully won't have these problems, but do monitor their usage and track who had use of the account at any time. Remind them that your company will be paying for all resources consumed.

Comment: I think my intentions were misrepresented.

To enable cloud practice, I plan to create an account for each user. The reason for creating on an account is that when creating an IAM User, issues such as risk of resource infringement between users and duplication of resource names may occur.

The question was what method could be used in this case.